# How to hide a custom button in detail page

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, custom-button, rendered

I have a custom button created whose logic which invokes a visualforce page. I have overridden the view button with a visualforce page that just displays the detail page of salesforce. The custom button is added to the detail page of the record.

View Page just has the below:

```
<apex:page standardController="object__c" extensions="controller">

 <apex:pageMessages />
 <apex:detail subject="{! object__c.id}"/>
</apex:page>
```

Controller logic:

```
public class controller{

private static final Map<String, ApexPages.Severity> severityMap = new Map<String, ApexPages.Severity>{'INFO' => ApexPages.Severity.INFO, 'ERROR' => ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'CONFIRM' => ApexPages.Severity.CONFIRM };
   public object__c recVar{get;set;}
   public String recordId;
    public VFPage(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
            recVar= (object__c) controller.getRecord();
            recordId = String.valueOf(sr.Id).substring(0, 15);
            String pageMessage = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('pageMessage');
            boolean doNotDisplay;
            String referrer = ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().get('REFERER');
            system.debug('############ the value ################' + referrer );
            if(referrer.contains(recordId + '/e')){
            doNotDisplay=false;
            }else{
            doNotDisplay=true;
            }
            System.debug('Do not display boolean %%%%%%%' + doNotDisplay);
          ApexPages.Severity whatSeverity;
          if(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('severity') !=NULL){
            whatSeverity = severityMap.get(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('severity'));
            System.debug('Severity %%%%%%%' + whatSeverity);
          }
        if (pageMessage != null && doNotDisplay) {
            ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.Message(whatSeverity , pageMessage));
            System.debug('pageMessage  Error **' + pageMessage );
        }



    }

}
```

The custom button has the reference to the below VF page:

```
<apex:page standardController="object__c" extensions="acontroller" action="{!makecallout}">
</apex:page>
```

The challenge here:

the challenge here is I want to disable the custom button based on a formula field value in the record. If the formula field return true I want to show the button else if it is false I do not want to show the button. How can I show and hide the button in the above VF page?

Comment: can you add the custom button code in the question

Comment: The 2nd visualforce page is behind the custom button. It calls the makecallout function.

Comment: pls add the custom button code in the 1st visualforce page in the question

Comment: Do you want to know the what is in the controller of the 1st VF page? The custom button code is part of 2nd VF page's controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved using Jquery as well. Create a formula field which hold the condition when the button should be shown/hidden. Use this field in VF page where you use Jquery to hide the button based on the name attribute of the button & the formula field. Like below:

```
<apex:includeScript value="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" />
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
if({!formula_field__c == 'true' }){
$('[name="buttonname"]').hide();
}
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `rendered` and `disabled` attribute of `apex:commandButton` for displaying or disabling based on formula condition.

Sample code looks like this:

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!callVFP}" 
value="callVisualforce" 
id="theButton" 
rendered="{!condition}" 
disabled="{!condition}"/>
```

Refer [apex:commandButton](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_commandButton.htm)

> - rendered - A Boolean value that specifies whether the component is rendered on the page. If not specified, this value defaults to true.
> - disabled - A Boolean value that specifies whether this button should be displayed in a disabled state. If set to true, the button appears disabled. If not specified, this value defaults to false.

**Update based on comments**

You cannot manage to show and hide custom button through `<apex:detail/>` tag.

If that is the situation, then you need to rebuild the page.

Otherwise, create recordtype and separate page layouts( with and w/o custom button) and update the record with proper recordtype.

Comment: Thanks. In my case I do not use <apex:commandButton> Instead I create a button and put it in detail page layout. Is there a way hide that type of button?

Comment: yes, possible, pls edit your question with that code

Comment: I have added the logic of controller of view page.(1st VF page ) where <apex:detail> tag is present. Please let me know how can I hide the button which is part of standard detail page.

Comment: pls see my updated answer and I think recordtype options will be good

Comment: I am unable to use <apex:commandbutton> with <apex:detail> page for some reason. Do you know why?

Comment: Here apex:detail will not work,  I have updated my answer

Comment: Ok, the other solution - Otherwise, create recordtype and separate page layouts( with and w/o custom button) and update the record with proper recordtype. Can you tell me how this can be acheived? Do I use it with apex:detail? I do not want to change my current design as it would require to test all functionalities again.

Comment: In that scenario apex:detail probably work, just update recordtypeid, system will try to display corresponding page layout

Comment: Using this option is there a way I do not show user which record type they should select?

Comment: make this as default recordtype so that it will not show up during record create. That is also configurable.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But I did found another work around for this. I used Jquery to hide the button :) which made my life easier.